# Getting an array to stop when user enters "-1"

Tags: c

My project is that I have to let the user enter 5000 numbers into an array, but allow them to stop whenever they please. I have most of the code down, but I can't figure out how to stop everything when the user inputs "-1" and then display the array. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define pause system("pause")
#define cls system("cls")
#define SIZE 50
int i;


main() 
{

int i;
int userInput[SIZE];

for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
{
    printf("Enter a value for the array (-1 to quit): ");
    scanf("%i", &userInput[i]);

} // end for

for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
{
    if (userInput[i] == -1) 
    printf("%i. %i\n", i + 1, userInput[i]);
    pause;
} // end for


pause;
  } // end of main
```

Answer (score 2):

In first `for` loop, add one if statement to check the input and break the loop if input is `-1`.

```
 for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    printf("Enter a value for the array (-1 to quit): ");
    scanf("%i", &userInput[i]);
    if(userInput[i] == -1){
      break; //break the for loop and no more inputs
    }
  } // end for
```

Also I think you want to display all the numbers entered by the user. If yes, then second loops should be as below:

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
   printf("%i. %i\n", i + 1, userInput[i]);
   if (userInput[i] == -1) {
      break; //break the for loop and no more outputs
   }
 } // end for
```

Comment: I'm not sure about programming convention in C, but if you don't want to use `break`, you can check the input as another condition for the loop.

Comment: I'm not following. So I would put an if statement after both for loops? Wouldn't it just stop after the first break and not display anything?

Comment: `break` only affects the loop that it's in. The `if` statement for the first loop makes the program stop asking for user input at -1. The second loop's `if` statement makes it so that the program only prints the things in the array up to the point where input was stopped.

Comment: @MatthewYoung: **`break` statement breaks the current loop only**. So your first for loop will stop as soon as user enter `-1`. Now the control will move out of that `for` loop and proceed with the next statement. Since you have stored the `-1` in your array, your second for loop will break when it reaches that index. I believe this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I finally got it to work. I always come on this site to look at others people's code, but I've never thought about posting my own question. Looks like I'll be posting here a lot more in the future... Thanks again!!

Comment: @MatthewYoung Good to know that it was helpful. Please don't forget to accept the answer.